# Ubuntu 19.10: Why can't I boot without nomodeset on? (Intel Graphics)

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, intel, nomodeset

I have an Asus Zenbook, and it absolutely refuses to boot without `nomodeset` in the GRUB settings. I have read that this is required sometimes for users with discrete graphics e.g. NVIDIA but this laptop only has Intel integrated so I don't know why it is acting like this.

`lspci -v` gives me this info:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    [virtual] Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I've attempted to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` but it informs me that I have the latest version installed already:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20190815-1).
```

Going to Additional Drivers shows that the AC wireless *Cannon Point-LP CNVi* isn't working, but doesn't tell me anything about my display drivers. What is there to do in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified your exact Zenbook model number, but I expect you are having this problem with panel EDID information not being recognized:

[Ubuntu not booting on Asus Zenbook UX431FA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199988/ubuntu-not-booting-on-asus-zenbook-ux431fa/1230984#1230984)

The solution is to download a valid EDID file that the OS understands. I got 1920x1080.bin from edid generator github. You then must place that file in `/lib/firmware/edid/` and boot with the kernel option `drm.edid_firmware=edid/1920x1080.bin`. For testing you can manually input that kernel option, and then if it works you can change it persistently in grub config.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the model and that was exactly it! That resolved my problem quick.